# node mcu not displaying RGB values

Tags: c, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

**Platform**

Hardware: ESP-01

Development Env: [Arduino IDE|

Operating System: [Windows|

**Settings in IDE**

Module: [Generic ESP8266 Module|

Flash Mode: [DOUT]

Flash Size: [512KB]

lwip Variant: |v2 Lower Memory|

Reset Method: [ck]

Flash Frequency: [40Mhz]

CPU Frequency: [80Mhz]

Upload Using: [SERIAL]

Upload Speed: [115200]

I'm using a Node mcu connected to a TCS3200 color sensor. But the serial monitor does not display the RGB value

**MY CODE :**

```
// TCS230 or TCS3200 pins wiring to Arduino
#define S0 D4
#define S1 D5
#define S2 D6
#define S3 D7
#define sensorOut D8

// Stores frequency read by the photodiodes
int redFrequency = 0;
int greenFrequency = 0;
int blueFrequency = 0;

void setup() {
  // Setting the outputs
  pinMode(S0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S3, OUTPUT);
  
  // Setting the sensorOut as an input
  pinMode(sensorOut, INPUT);
  
  // Setting frequency scaling to 20%
  digitalWrite(S0,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(S1,LOW);
  
   // Begins serial communication 
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
void loop() {
  // Setting RED (R) filtered photodiodes to be read
  digitalWrite(S2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(S3,LOW);
  
  // Reading the output frequency
  redFrequency = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
  
   // Printing the RED (R) value
  Serial.print("R = ");
  Serial.print(redFrequency);
  delay(100);
  
  // Setting GREEN (G) filtered photodiodes to be read
  digitalWrite(S2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(S3,HIGH);
  
  // Reading the output frequency
  greenFrequency = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
  
  // Printing the GREEN (G) value  
  Serial.print(" G = ");
  Serial.print(greenFrequency);
  delay(100);
 
  // Setting BLUE (B) filtered photodiodes to be read
  digitalWrite(S2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(S3,HIGH);
  
  // Reading the output frequency
  blueFrequency = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
  
  // Printing the BLUE (B) value 
  Serial.print(" B = ");
  Serial.println(blueFrequency);
  delay(100);
}
```

Problem :

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)
wdt reset
load 0x4010f000, len 3460, room 16 
tail 4
chksum 0xcc
load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 4 
tail 4
chksum 0xc9
csum 0xc9
v00042140
~ld
```

Comment: What do you think `wdt reset` means?

Comment: @Lundin I don't know.

Comment: How might you find out?

Comment: Watch Dog Timer reset. So how did you configure the watchdog? Is it enabled, is it disabled? Any embedded systems beginner learning material will mention what a watchdog is early on...

Comment: Also Google "wdt reset" will turn up plenty of material on it.